# Is boost.log officially part of Boost?

Tags: boost

I'm a bit confused as to the status of Boost.Log.  Is this an official part of Boost, or has it not been accepted yet?  When I google it, I see some posts talking about how it was accepted in 2010, etc, but when I look at the documentation for the last Boost libraries, I see no mention of it.

From what I can gather, there is a boost.log library available on sourceforge, however it needs to be extracted on top of an existing boost installation and compiled differently, so I'm basically confused as to whether or not it's official, or if it will ever be official.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Boost.Log` was accepted provisionally but is not yet an official part of Boost, it will be eventually.

Here is the review result:
http://lists.boost.org/boost-announce/2010/03/0256.php

---

**Update:** The release of *Boost 1.54.0* is the first one to include `Boost.Log`.

Comment: Thanks.  There was a mention of Boost.Log version 2 being the current one, but I couldn't find this anywhere, would you know anything about that, or is their SVN site the proper one to use?

Comment: @steve8918: According to the boost-dev mailing list, "Yes, the library is hosted at SourceForge, there is SVN repo with the latest source code. Trunk is v2 work in progress. <http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost-log>"